# Move docker images directory out of C drive on windows

Tags: docker, docker-image

I have pulled few windows images from docker hub which are stored in my C-Drive by default. (C:\ProgramData\Docker)

Please explain how I can move those to a different drive like D.

Comment: Are you using native docker for Windows or docker-tools for windows 7?

Comment: I am using native docker on windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the following article, worked for me in a Windows Server 2019 environment running Docker client and server version 20.10.7.

https://www.ntweekly.com/2019/09/20/how-to-change-docker-storage-data-folder-on-windows-server-2016/

Stop the docker service

```
stop-service docker
```

Edit following file, create it if not already there:

```
C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json
```

Add data-root element to the json string:

```
{
"data-root": "e:\\DockerData"
}
```

Restart the service:

```
restart-service docker
```

Beware, your images and containers aren't automatically moved to the new location, you need to manually relocate them.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to move the directory to the intended location, and then create a directory junction from the old location to the new one:

```
move C:\ProgramData\Docker D:\mypath\Docker
mklink /j C:\ProgramData\Docker D:\mypath\Docker
```

this causes Docker to believe that the data is still at `C:\ProgramData\Docker`, even though it isn't, and it will not take up any space on `C:`.

You can find a few other solutions at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/185 , but it appears that they don't work 100%.